# OSX Apple Mail client stops syncing GMail IMAP

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail, imap

Latest OSX version on a MacBook Pro.

On a regular basis, the Apple Mail client stops fetching new messages from GMail via IMAP.  Clicking on the "Fetch new mail" button does nothing.  It's possible to restart fetching by completely quitting and relaunching Apple Mail.

I've already looked at the following question [Apple Mail is not syncing completely with Gmail account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/235865/1941) and several others.

What I want to know is whether this is a known bug, a known incompatibility between Apple Mail and GMail, or something else, and whether there is a fix available (not just a workaround).

Comment: Gmail works great with mail for me. Have you tried signing out and in?

Comment: Yes, and that clears the problem for a short while, then it stops syncing again, unpredictably.

Comment: Are you using gsuite by any chance?

Comment: No gsuite, just a plain gmail account.